# How do I use kotlin codes to modify text appears in android emulator?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to build my very first app in android studio, "hello, world!" so I start a new project and add 2 lines of codes in the bottom.

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){ printHello()}
fun printHello () {println ("Hello World")}
```

(1)How do I use above 2 lines of kotlin codes to see the result in android emulator?
(2)In another project, I can modify "0" => "hello, world!"  from  res/layout/fragment_first.xml. But I see neither  nor fragment_first.xml so where do I go to modify?

[image]
[image]

```
package com.example.hello

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}

fun main(args:Array<String>){ printHello()}
fun printHello () {println ("Hello World")}
```

Error 1
[image]

Error 2
[image]

Error 3
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

1.

```
   fun main(args:Array<String>){ printHello()}  
   fun printHello () {println ("Hello World")}
```

the println would only show in andorid's log, to show something in the emulator, we can use Toast.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts

```
    fun main(args:Array<String>){ printHello()}  
    fun printHello () {Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
```

2. I think your other project is using another android studio's new project template, that's why it has res/layout/fragment_first.xml. you can modify res/layout/activity_main for this project

Full code here with minimal modification to your posted code. You should see the toast message when the app launch.

```
package com.example.hello

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        main(arrayOf())// notice the call to the function here
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    fun main(args:Array<String>){ printHello()}
    fun printHello () {Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
}
```

For building your first app, i would suggest going through the official first app guide,
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp

Comment: I see you (1) add import android.widget.Toast (2) modify my fun printHello (3)move 2 fun into class MainActivity{}. After I run it, red alert: Error running 'MainActivityKt': Class 'com.example.hello.MainAcitivtyKt' not found in module 'Hello.app'. How do I fix it?

Comment: Since I only add 2 lines from android studio's new project template. Before I asked this question, the emulator will run and show "hello_first_fragment" in the middle of the emulator screen. I didn't do anything after asking this question. But now when I remove your codes and my codes. Same red toast appears. Its a toast above the bottom "4:run"," Error running 'MainActivityKt': Class 'com.example.hello.MainAcitivtyKt' not found in module 'Hello.app'. "

Comment: it looks like you have renamed MainActivity to MainAcitivtyKt, maybe it would be easier to just create new project and paste the updated code instead of trying to figure out what went wrong since you are at the beginning of the project.
Again, i highly recommend building the first app with the official first app guide, it has great explanation on how android works, really helpful for beginner.

Comment: I did finish from the official site tutorial https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app-kotlin?hl=cs#9  (1)Following your guidance, I open a new project with basic activity and paste your codes but I still don't see "Hello World" print out and I do see "Hello first fragment" which is the original preset in the basic activity new project.

Comment: (2) I switch mainactivitykt to app from the dropdown menu in the top, left side of the emulator choice 4.7WXGA API 22. Then it can run. Previous red toast disappears. I didn't make this kotlin file and the new project doesn't have this kotlin file either. I attach 2 pictures in the end of my question. Do you know what this kotlin file, mainactivitykt , is? or how do I delete it?

Comment: (2)ans: you should select "app" for the drop down to run the application, MainActivity is the default activity that the app launch when start up, but the android studio is complaining because it cannot find MainActivity, as shown in the first picture, you have renamed MainActivity to MainActivityAA, thats why MainActivity is not found.

Comment: (1) ans: if you have created a new project, paste `Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()` as the last line of MainActivity.kt's onCreateView blcok, you should see the toast message show up when the app launch.
fun onCreateView(){
//skip
Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() 
}

Comment: For (1) ans: I didn't get it.  The following are the last 4 lines of my modified codes. Is this what you want me to do?    fun main(args:Array<String>){ printHello()}
    fun printHello () {Toast.makeText(this,"Hello Wind", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
    fun onCreateView(){Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
}

Comment: I don't have a onCreateView block in my original codes. Neither in the new project with basic activity nor your long answer codes above has onCreateView blocl. You asked me to paste Toast....show()  but  also add //skip Toast....show() in your onCreateView(){} so I am confused. Forgive me !! Is it possible you modify your long codes above that you posted the 1st time?

Comment: For (2) ans: How do I delete the MainActivityKt in the drop down menu since I don't suppose to choose it. When I choose app from the drop down menu. It can be run. But when I remove "AA" from "class MainActivityAA : AppCompatActivity()" of MainActivity.kt and remove AA from "tools:context=".MainActivityAA">" of activity_main.xml, then it can " Unfortunately, Hello has stopped." Why is that? I post this pic as Error 3 in the end of my question on top.

Comment: Why don't you just follow an Android tutorial @LisaBaron? You still seem to be taking about a main method, which won't do anything in Android.

Comment: I am following an Android tutorial now and I like to solve my previous problem as well.

Comment: I appreciate your time in answering my question. Since you have spent time, you must think my question have some value. Would you please up vote this question? This question will benefit others in the future as well.